# Is there a shortcut for commenting out multiple lines of code for .as files in Adobe Animate?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I'm new to Adobe Animate/Flash as well as this website so I hope this question is okay. I'm using a .as file in Adobe Animate to control my animation. I just need to be able to comment out and uncomment multiple lines of code easily, does anyone know how? Haven't found the answer online. Thanks.

Comment: I voted to close this post as off-topic. BTW, I think that you can use **Ctrl** + **M** to comment multiple selected lines ...

Comment: If all else fails just add a `/*` to begin the code block commenting and then use `*/` to close it. It's not a keyboard shortcut but...

Answer (score 2):

You can select your code and Ctrl+M to comment and to uncomment Ctrl+Shift+M